# Home directory not accessible: Permission denied. Working fine without sudo

Tags: python, linux, pulseaudio

I have a python script that is using pygame to load sound and play them. When I run my script without sudo, it is working fine. But when I run the script with sudo, I get these errors:

> Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
>
> ALSA lib pcm_mmap.c:341:(snd_pcm_mmap) mmap failed: Invalid argument

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening? I would like to understand what's going on and not only get a quick fix in case this happens again in another context and because I might need to run the script with `sudo`.

Comment: You should never need to run your script with sudo. To answer your question: it seems that sound device permissions are set to not allow root access, only user access. Or, perhaps root's home directory doesn't exist.

Comment: `Home directory not accessible: Permission denied` - run the program under `strace`. Does your program changes the user anywhere in it's execution? It would be strange to get `permission denied` for root. Check `whoami` output anywhere in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, pulseaudio won't work under `root`.

---

*The OP had edited the question with this; posting it as an answer instead.*